# g++ - "DSO missing from command line"

Tags: c++, boost, linker, g++, undefined-reference

I have quite a complex build which involves many static and shared libraries being linked into an executable on Ubuntu 14.04 using G++ 4.8.  The example is too complex to reproduce here, but it amounts to this:

I use functions from the boost filesystem library in my code, then archive that into a static library, call it `my_lib.a`.

I then link like this:

```
g++ -g -o Build/main -L Build/libs -Wl,--start-group ...lots of libraries here... \
    Build/libs/my_lib.a -lboost_filesystem -Wl,--end-group
```

When I run this, I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: Build/my_lib.a(my_code.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost10filesystem4pathdVERKS1_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

From what I can tell from Google, this means that I should add `-lboost_filesystem` to my link command-line - but it is already there!  I understand that the order of libraries is usually also important, but I thought that surrounding the objects and libraries with `-Wl,--start-group` and `-Wl,--end-group` should make that irrelevant - and in any case, I think I've got the order right.  So what's going on?

Comment: This could be related, http://stackoverflow.com/a/17988317/5781248

Comment: Thanks, I'll try some of those suggestions.

Comment: I've switched to boost 1.60.0, built from scratch using `--std=c++11` and it's made no difference to this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)