# checking directory paths ends with ".", ".."

Tags: c, linux

I have a programming problem that I hope someone out there can help me with. I am trying to learn C programming for a task at work and I have set myself a little project, which consists of reading down a file tree including all the sub directories obtaining information about each file.

The problem I get is that my program dosen't ignore the directory path ends with either /. or /.. and when it prints all the directories, I want to give space in front of the subdirectories for the readablity.

so the error is occured at this part:

```
int isDir(const char *parent, char *name) {

    struct stat st_buf; // file info
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    if (strcmp(name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(name, "..") == 0) {
        return 0;
    }   
    char *path = malloc(strlen(name) + strlen(parent) + 2);
    //sprintf(char *buf, const char *format, [arg1],[arg2],...)
    sprintf(path, "%s/%s", parent, name);
    stat(path, &st_buf); //

    return S_ISDIR(st_buf.st_mode); //directory
}
```

And this is main and list function:

```
int list(const char *name) {
    DIR *dirp = opendir(name);
    struct dirent *dentry;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    while ((dentry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
    char *dir_name = dentry->d_name;        

            printf(" %s\n", dir_name);

        //if it's dir, then go into dir
        if (isDir(name, dir_name)) { //name : parent, dir_name : child
            chdir(dir_name);
            getcwd(buf, BUF_SIZE);
            list(buf);
        }
    }
    closedir(dirp);
}

int main()
{
    list(".");
    return 0;
}
```

The result is like this:

> ```
> hm1.c
> Data
> lab1.txt
> result1
> lab3.txt
> .
> ..
> .
> ..
> result2
> lab3.txt
> .
> ..
> result3
> lab3.txt
> .
> ..
> a.c
> .
> ..
> a.out
> ```

result I want to print

> ```
> hm1.c
> Data
>     lab1.txt
>     result1
>         lab3.txt
>     result2
>         lab3.txt
>     result3
>         lab3.txt
> a.c
> a.out
> ```

Comment: Your `isDir()` function leaks memory every time it is called with something other than `.` or `..` in `name`.  You should also error check `malloc()` and `opendir()` at minimum — arguably `chdir()` and `getcwd()` too.

Comment: You're going to need an additional check for `.` and `..` before you print anything, and you'll probably want to pass an additional depth parameter to `list` so you can indent based on it.

Comment: Where is the `dir_name` used in `printf(" %s\n", dir_name);` defined, set, etc?  The `file_mode` and the `my_passwd` variables aren't used either.  Please consult the guidelines on making an MCVE ([MCVE]).  They make it easier for people to help you.  Your code shown appears to be reduced from your original, but not minimized and not verifiable.

Comment: I had an additional check for those before I print anything but that didn't work either :( and what is the depth parameter? @RetiredNinja

Comment: Inside the `while ((dentry = readdir(dirp)) != 0)` loop, use `if (strcmp(dentry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dentry->d_name, "..") continue;` before printing anything — and doing that allows you to simplify `isDir()`, too.  The 'depth' parameter would be triggered with `list(".", 0);` in `main()` and `int list(const char *dir, int level) { …; list(buf, level + 1); … }`.  And you'd use the level number to generate an appropriate number of spaces.  For example, `printf("%.*s", level * 4, "");` would generate 4 spaces per level.

Comment: sorry I'm still so confused. What does that "allows me to simplify     isDir()" mean? then I don't need to check ".", ".." inside the     isDir()? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Since the first change (skipping `.` and `..` in the `list()` function) means that `isDir()` is never called with `.` or `..` as an argument, you don't need the special case tests in `isDir()`.  As currently written, the function's name is inaccurate; it should be more like `isDirButNotDotOrDotDot()`.  With the extra test removed, the shorter name becomes accurate — though you don't ever use its ability to test that `.` and `..` are directories.

Comment: If you want to traverse a directory tree and do something with each file and/or directory, have a look at the POSIX `nftw()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `isDir` is returning true/false where it returns false (or zero) if you have `.` oe `..` and then the true/false value of `S_ISDIR` in other cases

What you really need is the function to return one of 3 values SKIP, isFILE or isDIR and then write your print logic based on that.

You also need to fix your memory leaks

Also note that `chdir(dir_name);` changes the actual directory of the process, so once you return from`list` within your loop you will no longer be able to open the files or directories that you are looping over (because you are now in a different directory)

This will fix your problems and print the format you want

```
enum { doSkip, isFile, isDir } testDir(char *path, char *name) 
{ 
     struct stat st_buf;        
     if (strcmp(name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(name, "..") == 0) {
         return doSkip;
     }   
     stat(path, &st_buf);
     if (S_ISDIR(st_buf.st_mode))
         return isDir;
     return isFile;
}

void list(const char *path, int indentlevel)
{
     DIR *dirp = opendir(path);
     struct dirent *dentry;
     char buf[10000]; // Lets just make the buffer sufficently big for this example
     if (!dirp) {
      printf("%*sNo access\n",indentlevel,"");
      return;
     }

     while ((dentry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {

        sprintf(buf,"%s/%s", path, dentry->d_name);
        switch (testDir(buf,dentry->d_name)) {
        case doSkip:
           /* do nothing */
           break;
        case isDir:
           printf("%*s%s:\n",indentlevel,"",dentry->d_name);
           list(buf,indentlevel+4);
           break;
        case isFile:
           printf("%*s%s\n",indentlevel,"",dentry->d_name);
           break;
        }
     }
     closedir(dirp);
}

int main()
{
     list(".", 0);
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, if you're willing to go to C++, is to use [`std::experimental::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem), also (mostly) known as [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm). With that, you would do something like:

```
#include <experimental/filesystem> // Could substitute <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::experimental;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    const auto path = filesystem::path{ argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "." };

    if( filesystem::is_directory(path) ) 
    {
        std::cout << path << " is a directory containing:\n";

        for( const auto& entry : boost::make_iterator_range( filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator{path}, {} ) )
        {
            std::cout << entry << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

See it run [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3366f981c0e8336b). Note that the directory iterators automatically skip `.` and `..`.

Comment: Your answer is C++ -- The OP is asking a C question

Comment: Right, which is why I said "if you're willing to go to C++". Since the OP has set this task to him/herself, C does not seem to be a hard requirement, and C++ has cross-platform, almost-standard facilities for handling it. As it is, it relies on Linux/POSIX functions explicitly. My solution does not and requires considerably less code to get right and maintain.

Comment: I was trying to see if I could get your example to work to understand the *magic* of the recursive-iterator, and see if the output can be formatted as per specification -- but im getting down a rabbit hole of boost linking issues like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634114/cant-link-program-using-boost-filesystem  -- I must say, I have never been a fan of boost, so im giving up without being able to make it run

Comment: My example runs with std::experimental at the link provided. Boost can be tricky to *build* right, but you may also be able to just install it from your Linux distro and use that.