# Build Boost with C++11 support for selected libraries

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I'm trying to build boost (1.65) on linux with C++11 support to link with my other project (also compiled with C++11 support).

However, I get this kind of error (which seems to happen because my boost is not compiled with c++11):

```
undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::current_path(boost::system::error_code*)'
data_parser.cc:(.text+0xf15): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::absolute(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&)'
data_parser.cc:(.text+0x142e): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
data_parser.cc:(.text+0x1790): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
```

Here is my command line:

```
./b2 --prefix=boost-install --with-filesystem --with-system --with-program_options --with-thread link=static variant=release cxxflags='-std=c++11' install
```

But I noticed during compilation if I compile without any --with- (so with all libraries), I can see this line:

```
- C++11 mutex              : yes
```

and some other lines related to c++11, however as soon as I add a --with- (e.g. --with-thread), all lines relative to c++11 disappear.

I also tried to add `#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS` around `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` but it doesn't change anything.

I have no clue what is going on here, if someone can help me.

Thank you.

**Update:** Here is the command of the linking command:

```
/usr/bin/c++   -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG   CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/MyProject.cc.o  -o MyProject  -L/home/whiteshadow/code/MyProject-build/deps/boost-install/lib  -L/home/whiteshadow/code/MyProject-build/deps/zlib-install/lib  -L/home/whiteshadow/code/MyProject-build/deps/nifticlib-install/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/whiteshadow/code/MyProject-build/deps/boost-install/lib:/home/whiteshadow/code/MyProject-build/deps/zlib-install/lib:/home/whiteshadow/code/MyProject-build/deps/nifticlib-install/lib: -rdynamic ../deps/zlib-install/lib/libz.a ../deps/nifticlib-install/lib/libznz.a ../deps/nifticlib-install/lib/libnifticdf.a ../deps/nifticlib-install/lib/libniftiio.a -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_program_options DataStructure/libDataStructure.a FileHandler/libFileHandler.a Parser/libParser.a Tools/libTools.a -lpthread FileHandler/libFileHandler.a FileHandler/libFileHandler.a Tools/libTools.a DataStructure/libDataStructure.a
```

I don't think it comes from a mis-linking issue, because if I remove -lboost_filesystem I have much more linking errors. Here I only have 7, related to only 3 functions (boost::filesystem::detail::status, boost::filesystem::detail::current_path and boost::filesystem::absolute).

Also, in libboost_filesystem.a, I'm able to find symbols for these 3 functions:

(boost::filesystem::detail::status)

```
00000000000026d0 T _ZN5boost10filesystem6detail6statusERKNS0_4pathEPNS_6system1‌​0error_codeE
```

(boost::filesystem::detail::current_path)

```
0000000000000c90 T _ZN5boost10filesystem6detail12current_pathEPNS_6system10error_codeE
```

(boost::filesystem::absolute)

```
0000000000001100 T _ZN5boost10filesystem8absoluteERKNS0_4pathES3_
```

Comment: Are you seeing the undefined reference error while building boost or while trying to build your project? And how did you conclude those linker errors have anything to do with C++11?

Comment: I see these errors while linking boost to my project. I googled the errors and found this thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634114/cant-link-program-using-boost-filesystem) but the solutions proposed didn't work for me.

Comment: Please update your question with the linker command line which causes the error above. You're mostly likely missing one or both of `-L/path/to/boost/libs -lboost_filesystem`. You may also need to link to `boost_system`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I include the lib directory and the -lboost_filesystem. Here is a short version of my linking command: -L/home/whiteshadow/code/MyProject-build/deps/boost-install/lib  -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_program_options  -lpthread

Comment: I don't think it's a missing library at linking issue, because I only have 7 linking errors related to filesystem, if I wasn't linking it properly I would have much more. Also, in these 7 errors, it only concerns 3 functions (boost::filesystem::detail::status, boost::filesystem::detail::current_path and boost::filesystem::absolute).

Comment: I checked in the libboost_filesystem.a and I found the reference to boost::filesystem::detail::status (00000000000026d0 T _ZN5boost10filesystem6detail6statusERKNS0_4pathEPNS_6system10error_codeE) as well as for current_path and absolute functions, so I don't understand why it is 'undefined'.

Comment: Time to create a [mcve]. Use a few of those functions in your test code and see if you can reproduce the error.

Comment: I tested with a simple program, calling the same function as my code, linked to the same boost library, and it compiles properly (with almost the same command).

Comment: The order of libraries on the command line must be as follows. `a-library-that-uses-boost-filesystem.a -lboost-filesystem`. Not the other way around.

Comment: Yes, I just realized I was linking boost after some libraries using it. I always forget that order matters. Is it not possible to make a system that looks for previously loaded symbols when linking? That would be so much easier. Anyway, thank you so much.

Comment: Use `-Wl,--start-group -lfoo -lbar ... -Wl,--end-group`