# Conflict between two boost versions

Tags: c++, boost, autotools

I have two versions of boost installed on cluster. The old one is in standard location while the new one in my home directory. Since I have no su privilege I cannot delete the old one. I exported environment variables for boost (and for other libraries) as follows:

```
export PATH=/truba/home/osibliyev/boost/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/truba/home/osibliyev/boost/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=/truba/home/osibliyev/boost/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/truba/home/osibliyev/boost/include:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

After compiling with `make`, I get the following error at linking stage:

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_serialization.so.1.64.0, needed by
>   /truba/home/osibliyev/boost/lib/libboost_mpi.so, may conflict with
>   libboost_serialization.so.1.53.0 /usr/bin/ld: loadmap.o: undefined
>   reference to symbol '_ZN5boost7archive17archive_exceptionC2ERKS1_'
>   /truba/home/osibliyev/boost/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.64.0:
>   error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

`lboost_serialization` is already added to `LDADD`:

```
LDADD = -lmetis -lmpi -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization -lboost_log -lboost_log_setup -lboost_thread -lpthread -lboost_date_time -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_timer
```

I am sort of sure that the error is because of conflict because other libraries are linked without problem and only boost complains. This does not happen on my machine where there is only one boost version. What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: If you search _DSO missing from command line_ on SO, you get a bunch of possible answers. Have you already read them? This looks a lot like a duplicate question. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15634114/4987285) is one that probably can help you.

Comment: @skypjack Yes, I searched for similar questions but none of them solve my problem. Besides the problem occurs only in cluster not in my PC. This makes me think the problem is existence of two boost versions but don't know how to get rid of the old version.

Comment: The problem is not getting rif of the old version, but rather of making the newer version be chosen instead.  As far as I am aware, none of the environment variables you describe setting will have that effect.  Instead, you want to add an `-L/truba/home/osibliyev/boost/lib` option to `LDADD`, before any of the `-l` options specifying Boost libraries.  You will, however, need the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at *run* time.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Your solution works. But which environment variable can do the same functionality? BTW, you might want to answer so that I can choose it as best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How your toolchain's header and library search paths are determined is implementation-specific.  There is no universal rule for what environment variables, if any, affect them, or how.

The specific environment variables you are trying to use and the values you are setting for them indicate a UNIX-style system.  You should be aware that

- on such a system, the `PATH` variable sets the search path for executables, not libraries or headers.
- on those systems that recognize it, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` designates extra directories for the *dynamic* linker's search path -- these are relevant at run time, not build time.
- `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` is recognized by the GNU C++ compiler, and maybe others, for designating additional directories to search for include files.  This is relevant to you for finding the Boost headers, but not the libraries.  With GNU compilers, the directories listed in this variable will be searched before the standard directories.
- `LIBRARY_PATH` is recognized by the GNU linker, and possibly others, as designating additional directories to search for libraries.  Like `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`, this is relevant to you, but it does not allow you to substitute your libraries for like-named others found in one of the standard locations, because the standard directories are searched *before* these.

Your error messages suggest that The linker is finding a mixture of Boost v1.53 and v1.64 libraries.  Probably that means that the former reside in a directory that is search first -- likely a system directory such as `/usr/lib` -- but not all the Boost libraries you are trying to link are found there; some are found in your v1.64 installation.  Given that what you've already tried does not work, there is unlikely to be any environment variable you can set to fix that.  As I said, however, it's implementation-dependent, and although I suspect you're using the GNU toolchain, you haven't specified.

With the GNU toolchain, if you want the linker to search your personal Boost installation for libraries before it searches the standard directories then you'll need to instruct it specifically to do so via command-line option.  As discussed in comments, you can accomplish that by adding `-L/truba/home/osibliyev/boost/lib` to your Automake `LDADD` variable.